# How do I check if the name is already taken in database? React + Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend

I want to make a Validator that validates uniqueness of items. If i want to create new stuff, I want to check if I have it in the database already first.

Code:

```
const [categList, setCategList] = useState([]);


  const getItems = () => {
    // Sending HTTP GET request
    Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      const categories = [];
      response.data.forEach((resCateg) => {
        categories.push(resCateg.name + ", " + resCateg.description);
        console.log(resCateg);
      });
      setCategList(categories);
    });
  };
```

And before i do:

```
function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //reset form validation errors
    resetFormValidationErrors();


    Axios.post(url, {
      // Sending HTTP POST request
      name: data.name,
      description: data.description,
    }).then((res) => {
      resetForm();
    });
  }
```

I want to check under "preventDefault" that my name is unique. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to check only the name ? or want to check description also to be unique?

Comment: I need just the name to be unique

Comment: And yeah, you can get the name like this: ```var singleName = categList.split(',')[0]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to store names in your state and then you can check from that array if your name already exist or not.

Here's How to do it-

```js
const [categList, setCategList] = useState([]);

const getItems = () => {
    // Sending HTTP GET request
    Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        const categoryNames = response.data.map(res => res.name)
        setCategList(categoryNames);
    });
};
```

Check while submitting -

```js
function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //reset form validation errors
    resetFormValidationErrors();

    // Checking here if `categList` already includes name
    if(categList.includes(data.name.trim())) {
        alert(`${data.name} is already taken, Please select any other name.`)
        return
    }

    Axios.post(url, {
        // Sending HTTP POST request
        name: data.name,
        description: data.description,
    }).then((res) => {
        resetForm();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm1

Comment: There is still one problem. Now, i can't list my description on screen. How do i solve that?

Comment: You need to list description by putting comma with name ?

Comment: Yes, but i still want only name to be checked

Comment: Okay, Giving you the updated code here in comment.

Comment: ```Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        const categories = response.data.map(res => ({name: res.name, desription: res.description}))
        setCategList(categories);
    });
```

And check like this in your submit function.
```if(categList.map(c => c.name).includes(data.name.trim())) {
    alert("your message")
}
```

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, desription}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

That is the error i get now

Comment: How are you showing in view. Send me the code. I will update and send you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239372/discussion-between-milos-milutinov-and-anuj-raghuvanshi).